# I will not/would not

Tags: will-would

If someone asks me "would you give me your bike", which one of the following will be the usual reply?

1- No, I won't give you my bike.

2- No, I wouldn't give you my bike.

My question is should I be using 'would' to reply as the question is asked with 'would'?

Answer (score 2):

**My question is should I be using 'would' to reply as the question is asked with 'would'?**

No, the use of the word *would* in the question doesn't force the use of *would* in the answer. Your first answer is fine.

Furthermore, the original question can be interpreted in one of two ways: either the person is really asking for your bike, or else the person is merely posing a hypothetical scenario.

In the latter case, if you wanted to keep the conversation in the realm of the hypothetical, then you'd use *wouldn't* instead of *won't*.

It's also worth noting that the "mismatch" can go the other way around, too, and the conversation still sounds normal:

> **Bob**: Will you give me your bike?
>   **Rob**: *No, I wouldn't give you my bike*.

In that case, Rob is more or less saying that the answer is *no*, and that he can't think of any possible reason that his mind could be changed.